# Print Taxonomy ID of Node

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I am trying to print taxonomy ID of a node in the node body. In D7 there is no views filed to do that, so can someone help me with the PHP code?

Comment: There's no more `$node->taxonomy` in Drupal 7, terms are attached to nodes by way of a term reference field. Have you added such a field to the content type?

Comment: Yes I have added term reference fields to the content type

Comment: If you add a relationship based on that reference field, you should have access to the tid/name/anything else you need

Comment: yes, but I am actually trying to print the node's term ID in a view contextual filter, and pass it to the views which are add in the header of the same view.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to explain...nodes don't have a 'term ID' any more. They have a _field_ which references one or more taxonomy terms. At the most basic level this might be at `$node->field_name[$node->language][0]['tid']`, but it completely depends on your setup

Comment: I an totally agree with @Clive

Comment: Yup, I agree... I did not get the concept of using views relationships. I would like to avoid coding as much as possible here.

Comment: It'll just be a matter of getting used to the Views interface @AnAnD, there shouldn't be any need for custom code here at all